# LiftWeb Loc.Template arguments

Tags: scala, lift

I have Template and two snippets. Can I get Id in Template for select dynamic snippet.

```
def remote =
  Menu.param[Point]("Test1", "remote",
  id => inTransaction(Points.lookup(id)), _.id) / "point" / * / "remote" >>
  //inTransaction(Points.lookup(id)) match
  //  case point.Kind.remote =>
  Loc.Template(() => Templates("point" :: "remote" :: Nil).openOr(Nil)) >> Hidden
  //  case point.Kind.otherremote =>
  //Loc.Template(() => Templates("point" :: "otherremote" :: Nil).openOr(Nil)) >> Hidden
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ValueTemplate` instead, it provides the current parsed value is parameter.

Code below is untested but you should get the idea:

```
def remote = Menu.param[Point]("Test1", "remote",
  id => inTransaction(Points.lookup(id)), _.id) / "point" / * / "remote" >>
  Loc.ValueTemplate(point => point match
    case Full(p) if p.Kind.remote => Templates("point" :: "remote" :: Nil).openOr(Nil))
    case Full(p) if p.Kind.otherremote => Templates("point" :: "otherremote" :: Nil).openOr(Nil))
    case _ => NodeSeq.Empty
  ) >> Hidden
```